# Psychological thriller involving woman in disguise

Tags: identify-this-movie

I saw a movie a good few years ago but I cannot remember the name of it at all.

It was a psychological thriller. I'm almost certain it was made in the 2000s. Set in America.

There is a woman on the phone in her apartment in one scene near the beginning.

I think someone belonged to her dies or is killed early on in the movie.

I think there are people after her because of links she has to some people or something of importance.

At the end of the film she goes into a bank in disguise wearing a wig and is able to retrieve lots of money.

I cannot remember the name or any of the actors/actresses that were in it. It was a great movie but I have no way of finding out the name of it. Please help!

She was in her 20s or 30s, American accent. She was white. I think she actually had blonde hair when not wearing the wig (I remember it being a black wig).

I'm not sure if the money was rightfully hers but she got away with it. I'm almost certain it was money the villains were after.

Comment: I just discovered myself that the movie is actually Columbus Circle (2012) starring Selma Blair, Amy Smart and Kevin Pollak.

Answer (score 5):

<sub>Expanding [comment](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/72372/psychological-thriller-involving-woman-in-disguise#comment117732_72372) into a proper answer.</sub>

#### It is [*Colombus Circle* (2012)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Columbus_Circle_(film)).

Here's the plot from [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Columbus_Circle_(film)#Plot) of the film.

> **The film is about an heiress who has shut herself inside her Columbus Circle apartment for nearly two decades**. A detective investigating the death of one of her neighbors and the duo who move into the subsequently vacant apartment force her to face her fears of the outside world.

In the movie, one of the neighbors of woman in the lead role Abigail Clayton (Selma Blair) is killed.

Yes, the movie is set in America. The apartment of Abigail is in Manhattan. Some parts of the movie are shot in Los Angeles, America. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Columbus_Circle_(film)#Production) also confirms it.